# Install SSL Cert on vSphere Client 6.7

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot, vsphere-client

I'd like to install SSL Cert on vSphere Client 6.7. I tried with Let's Encrypt using [this method](https://jjasghar.github.io/blog/2017/11/14/vcenter-vcsa-and-using-lets-encrypt/), but I can't add a DNS record. I can't use preferred-challenges=http with Certbot either because the server is not internet-facing.

So my question:
Is there another way to get a public key or is self-signed the only way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server you actually want to get the certificate for isn't Internet-facing, you could always put up a "dummy" machine on the name(s) you want to get the certificate for and perform HTTP-01 validation that way.  Alternately, Let's Encrypt isn't the only CA in existence, and others do support other domain-control validation methods.